# Bitcoin-Core re-synchronizing after updating to v0.18.0

Tags: bitcoin-core

I recently updated Bitcoin-Core to 0.18.0 and then it had to resync the blocks which has taken 8 days so far and is only on 67% completed (using windows 7). I have the files saved in D:/.. I noticed the config file was blank. What should be written in there in a standard case?

I did try to install node launcher but was to technical for me, but after I tried this I noticed I had another bitcoin folder in F:/ which I have since deleted.

Comment: What is a "node launcher"?

Comment: What did you update from?  A blank configuration file is fine.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Bitcoin Core does not create a configuration file. If you want to change configuration options, you can either pass startup parameters or add the `bitcoin.conf` yourself.

Comment: I updated from the previous version 0.17, I have just realised that my IP address I used for port 8333 in router had reassigned its self,so this is why I had no incoming connections,  but it’s still processing v slowly, increase per hour is 0.02%. The number of blocks left is unknown and says is syncing headers?

Comment: @MarkRichards: Bitcoin Core will first download all headers of the blocks to determine the best chain, then download and verify the complete best chain. It sounds like you're still in the first phase. Is this a microcomputer?

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so would say I still have a way to go, I  am just using an old laptop around 10 years old

Answer (score 0):

[v0.18.0 release notes](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5138532.0) include:

> ### systemd init file
>
> The systemd init file (`contrib/init/bitcoind.service`) has been
>   changed to use `/var/lib/bitcoind` as the data directory instead of
>   `~bitcoin/.bitcoin`. This change makes Bitcoin Core more consistent
>   with other services, and makes the systemd init config more consistent
>   with existing Upstart and OpenRC configs.

So, to prevent a slow re-sync, you'd need to move your old data directory to the new location.  Although the release notes specify the data directory used to be `~bitcoin/.bitcoin`, mine on v0.17.1 was in `/var/lib/bitcoin/.bitcoin`, which I just needed to move to `/var/lib/bitcoind` to prevent a re-sync.