# Bitcoin Core resynching after updating from 0.19 to 25.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

Similar to [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/87673/107317) after upgrading Bitcoin core from version 0.19 to 25, it is re-synching and ignoring the already synched blocks.

This is a quite a large version jump, there doesn't seem to be a difference in location of the blocks, is there a way to upgrade without re-synching?

Comment: Are you running a pruned node or a node that keeps the complete blockchain?

Comment: @Murch running a full node